# Php error displaying data in input

Tags: php, html, css

This piece of code is working fine, what I want to is why if I remove the foreach($rows as $row) I gt an error, is there a way to display the data without using it.

```
<?php
require("coneccion.php");

if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
{
  header("Location: index.php");
  die("Redirecting to index.php");
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$nombre = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
$query = "SELECT c.coursename FROM courses as c WHERE c.courseid = $id and c.id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$nombre') ";

try
{
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
  die("Error");
}

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
?> 
  <?php 
  foreach($rows as $row):    
    echo '<input type="text" name="coursename" value="' .htmlentities($row['coursename']) . '" />'; 

    endforeach;
```

Comment: You need the foreach to get to every result of the array, why would you want to remove the foreach?

Comment: You have to use a loop structure to fetch all details.. you can use foreach() or while() loop for doing this.

Comment: Because I only need to display one result

Comment: Ah, that is interesting information. You _could_ have posted that in the question... In that case just use `$rows[0]`. Or, even better, just retrieve the first row: `$row = $stmt->FetchRow()`.

Comment: Great, those people able to copy and paste my comment into a real answer. Great. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're working with the standard PDO settings, you can access the first returned result like so:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="coursename" value="' .htmlentities($rows[0]['coursename']) . '" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

To return the first row in your array you could do:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="coursename" value="'
.htmlentities($rows[0]['coursename']) . '" />';
```

Which will return the first row, but I dont recommend this. PHP array are hashtables they are incredibly fast you don't save yourself any style points by making your code less maintainable.